# how to take a linked list and a function pointer as inputs

Tags: c, list, function, declaration, singly-linked-list

I am new to C and trying to learn function pointer.I am supposed to  complete the 'map_list'function which takes a linked list and a function pointer,and return a new list in the same order, but with all the values squared.Please point it out where I did wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


struct Link {
    struct Link *next;
    int value;
};

void print_list(struct Link *list) {
    for(struct Link *l = list; l != NULL; l = l->next) {
        printf("%d", l->value);

        if(l->next) {
            printf(", ");
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
}


struct Link *append(int x, struct Link *head) {
    struct Link *head_ = (struct Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    head_->next = head;
    head_->value = x;

    return head_;
}

struct Link *reverse_list(struct Link *list) {
    struct Link *head = NULL;

    for(struct Link *l = list; l != NULL;) {
        struct Link *next = l->next;
        l->next = head;
        head = l;

        l = next;
    }

    return head;
}

struct Link *map_list(struct Link *link_list,int (*Square)(int)   ) {

    struct Link *new_list = NULL;
    new_list = new_list ->next;
    new_list ->value = (*Square)(link_list ->value);
    return new_list;
}

int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}

int add3(int x) {
    return x + 3;
}



struct Link *theList() {
    struct Link *l = append(1, NULL);
    l = append(2, l);
    l = append(3, l);
    l = append(5, l);
    return l;
}

int main() {


    struct Link *l = theList();
    print_list(map_list(l, &square));
    ;
    return 0;
}
```

I got 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

Comment: Think about the lines `struct Link *new_list = NULL;` and `new_list = new_list ->next;`. How will that work? And for the rest of the function, how would a new list be created (or the original modified) without any iteration?

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct Link *head_ = (struct Link*)malloc(sizeof(struct Link));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `struct Link *reverse_list(struct Link *list) {`   Your question did not mention anything about reversing the order of the list, so why this function?   Please post a [mcve]

Comment: OT:  it  is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used:  Suggest removing the statements: `#include <stdbool.h>` `#include <string.h>`  and `#include <ctype.h`

Comment: OT: parameter and variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  Names like `l` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct LINK *theList()` says the parameter list can be anything (including no parameters.  It is much better, in a prototype or (as in the posted code) the first declaration of that signature to include `void` between the parens

Comment: regarding: `struct LINK *map_list(struct LINK *link_list,int (*Square)(int)   )`  why complicate your problem by passing a function pointer?

Comment: in function: `map_list()` regarding: `struct LINK *new_list = NULL;
    new_list = new_list ->next;`   This actually says.   1) set a pointer to address 0  2) at offset 0 read a value  3) set the pointer to that value   This is a prime way to cause a seg fault event.

Comment: in the function: `append()` both a parameter and local variable are named `head`   so there needs to be a careful examination of the C standard to determine exactly which `head` is being referenced at each reference.   Strongly suggest changing the local variable name to something else

Comment: OT: regarding: `for(struct LINK *l = list; l != NULL; l = l->next)`  There is no need to compare `l != NULL`   rather simple state: `for(struct LINK *l = list; l; l = l->next)`

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct Link 
{
    struct Link *next;
    int value;
};`   It is typical to write struct names and `#define` names in all caps,  similar to: `struct LINK 
{
    struct LINK *next;
    int value;
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you have some trouble with writing the function `map_list`.
It can look the following way

```
struct Link * map_list( const struct Link *link_list, int operation( int )   ) 
{
    struct Link *new_list  = NULL;
    struct Link **new_node = &new_list;

    for ( const struct Link *current = link_list; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Link ) );

        ( *new_node )->next  = NULL;
        ( *new_node )->value = operation( current->value );

        new_node = &( *new_node )->next;
    } 

    return new_list;
}
```

And the function can be called for example like

```
map_list( l, square );
```

or

```
map_list( l, add3 );
```

The function does not check whether a memory allocation for a node was successfull. You can add such a check yourself.

As for your own function implementation

```
struct Link *map_list(struct Link *link_list,int (*Square)(int)   ) {

    struct Link *new_list = NULL;
    new_list = new_list ->next;
    new_list ->value = (*Square)(link_list ->value);
    return new_list;
}
```

then for starters it has undefined behavior

```
ew_list = new_list ->next;
```

and does not make sense relative to the assignment.